# Lambda timeout accessing redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect to Redshift cluster via python lambda function. I've checked the following for the lambda:

- Role for lambda

  - AmazonRedshiftFullAccess
  - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
- VPC enabled for lambda

  - Inbound (Protocol = All, Ports = All, source = SG1)
  - Outbound (Protocol = All, Ports = All, destination = 0.0.0.0/0)

For the redshift cluster, it is in the same VPC as lambda and not publicly accessible. So in the lambda environment, I had used the redshift private IP.

However, when I try running the lambda, it timeout after the x seconds still.

Comment: How is the redshift security group configured? Does it allow inbound access from the lambda?

Comment: Also, you could optionally use access analyzer to check for connectivity issues.

Comment: Hm the access analyzer result is Reachable :(

Comment: You have to whitelist the security group of the lambda functions in the inbound rules of the Redshift cluster (5439). Are you using domain name or IP address to connect to the redshift cluster? Were the DNS settings in the redshift cluster working?

Answer (score 1):

The security configuration should be:

- The AWS Lambda function should be connected to the same VPC as the Amazon Redshift cluster
- A Security Group on the AWS Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) that has the default "Allow All" rules for Outbound connections
- A Security Group on the Redshift database (`Redshift-SG`) that permits Inbound connections on port 5439 from `Lambda-SG`

That is, the `Redshift-SG` should specifically reference the `Lambda-SG` (by `sg-` ID) in the Inbound rule. This will permit the Lambda function to communicate with the Redshift database.